# How to drop only files in windows forms form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form and I want to be able to drop files on it. I have the following code:

```
private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) 
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}
```

I want the cursor to change *only* when I am dropping files, and not when I drop directories. The above code changes it for directories as well. What am I doing wrong? Is there any data format for files, or should I simply try to check the object I get in e.Data for extension?

Comment: Is there any reason NOT to check for a file extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the data using `File.Exists` ? I think it will return true if it is a file, and false if it isn't.

Here is an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx):

```
        if(File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            // This path is a file
            ProcessFile(path); 
        }               
        else if(Directory.Exists(path)) 
        {
            // This path is a directory
            ProcessDirectory(path);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  I would think doing file access in the middle of a mouse drag would cause hiccups and stuttering.

Comment: @SteveWellens it won't if you do it ONCE not for every mouse move that occurs (clipboard will be static at the time of dragging)

Comment: @DanielMošmondor - If it's a file on a network drive or CD or some other slow media (like the cloud) it might.  But I haven't tried it either.